# Online sources for elevation values and resources distribution

Tags: geospatial

I'm looking for an open database from which I can download, for a selected area, both the elevation map (usually I use [this one](http://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/)) and a map of the resources underground (ideally it should be oil or gas). As a resolution, between 30 and 90 meters would be perfect. Do you have suggestions on where to look? As a file format, I would prefer to work with `.hgt`, `.flt` or `.hdr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable approach would be to obtain layers of (1) elevation data such as SRTM and (2) natural resources and overlay them.

For (1), see [EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) and look under the section "Digital Elevation".  Note that the link you posted is likely your best best for the data in `.hgt` format.  For (2),  the U.S. Energy Information Administration has [a set of maps and geospatial datasets (i.e. Shapefiles)](https://www.eia.gov/maps/maps.htm) on oil and natural gas resources.  Alternatively, the [USGS National Geologic Map Database](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/ngmdb/ngmdb_home.html) might have some useful data on land resources.  Under a broader definition "resources underground", the [list of USDA ERS Natural Resources Datasets](https://www.ers.usda.gov/about-ers/partnerships/strengthening-statistics-through-the-icars/natural-resources-datasets/) has several interesting sources for geospatial data on natural resources.  Note that since the specifics were omitted in the OP, I have assumed a geographic scope of the United States.